# How to log all HTTPS POST requests with URL from and URL to?

Tags: ubuntu, https

I need a log for my Ubuntu server to log all incoming HTTPS PORT requests and see URL from it was sent and to what URL it was sent, also a time.

```
Log format should be:
time IP URL_FROM URL_TO
```

And another log to all HTTPS incomming requests with URL from and URL TO with time.

```
Log format should be:
time PROTOCOL IP URL_FROM URL_TO
```

How this is posible? It would be absolutely amazing and very usable for other cases.

I have been trying `tcpdump`, `tshark`, `ngrep` and a lot of other commands/packages but with no success, because a lot of additional information is given, but I need only these, also one request per line, because server is receiving hundreds of them in second.

Answer (score 1):

URL FROM doesn't make sense, requests don't come from URLS, they come from IP addresses. The rest (including the source IP address) will be in (or can be configured to be in) your (unnamed) http server access logs.

Comment: We can receive URL FROM when loging in apache2 service. But I need a log to get all requests before apache, because I think apache doesn't receive all requests in my case. But I understand that it can not be posible to get URL FROM in tcpdump or other commands. But still, I need confirmation for this before searching another methods. Thank you!

Comment: By "URL From" do you mean the referer? (If a user is on "page a" and clicks a link to "page b", the server will receive a request for "page b", but the browser will also inform the server, via the `Referer` header, that the user came from "page a")